# Should I rely on copy elision or on move semantics?

Tags: c++, c++17

Given a vector

```
std::vector<BigObject> v;
```

and a factory function

```
BigObject genBigObject();
```

I want to avoid copying `BigObject` instances.

Which one is faster ?

```
v.push_back(genBigObject());
```

or

```
v.push_back(std::move(genBigObject()));
```

Can I rely on the fact that copy elision will *allways* happen ? (I could remove the copy constructor on `BigObject`, but, well...)

Comment: You might want to take a look at emplace_back: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: @CelalErgün Since the object construction happens inside of a function, I don't think using `emplace_back` would change anything. It would the same effect as `push_back`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The purpose of `std::move()` is to take an *lvalue* and treat it as an *rvalue* to make it clear for other functions down the road that they can cannibalize the object's internals if they so wish.

`genBigObject()` is already an rvalue. You do not need to `move()` it to make it one - `move()` simply doesn't provide you anything of value there. So just don't do it. You don't even need to get into the question of what actually happens downstream - `move()` is a signal for code and for readers that you're doing something potentially unsafe, but in this case... you're not.

For this *specific* case, you're calling the rvalue reference overload of `push_back()` anyway - which triggers a temporary materialization of the temporary object. Whether that temporary materialization happens because of specifically the call to `push_back()` or the slightly-earlier call to `move()` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Makes total sense: it is an rvalue. However if I were to store the `BigObject` instance in a temporary variable, that would make it an lvalue and I would need to transform the temporary variable to an rvalue with `std::move` before pushing. Right ?

Comment: @BrunoGrieder If you mean `BigObject b = genBigObject(); v.push_back(std::move(b));` then yes - `b` is an lvalue there (note, it's `b`, specifically the name, that's the lvalue) so `move(b)` does have an effect

Answer (score 2):

Elision will not happen there, see @Barry's answer for details.

In short, `push_back` does not support elision; it takes an rvalue reference or a const lvalue reference.

You have an actual rvalue; calling `std::move` casts that rvalue into an rvalue reference, which is a pointless action.  It is like `int x = 7; static_cast<int&>(x);` -- almost a noop, and sometimes a pessimization.

Addressing your core concern, that you want elision, we can do something.

You can elide the construction of `BigObject` with a bit of work:

```
template<class F>
struct emplacer {
  F f;
  operator std::result_of_t<F&&()>()&&{ return std::forward<F>(f)(); }
  operator std::result_of_t<F&()>()&{ return f(); }
};
template<class T>
emplacer(T&&)->emplacer<T&&>;
```

now you can do this:

```
v.emplace_back( emplacer{ &getBigObject });
```

and the `BigObject` will be directly emplaced into the vector buffer (barring overly greedy `BigObject` constructors).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d9f329949761522) (notice the complete lack of output; we generated 100 BigObject in a vector and zero where moved).

Comment: Interesting! I do not particularly "want" elision... unless I can have a performance gain. Thank you for your example, starting from there, i will run a few benchmarks.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder So, if your big object is a  handle to a large amount of resources on the heap, move is usually near-free.  If your big object is like `struct BigObject { std::array< 1 bajillion, char > }` then you *need* elision for efficiency.